# Unity's StartCoroutine funtionality inside a .NET Library and outside a MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript, .net

This code is used in a MonoBehaviour script in my current code:

```
    // a simple WWW post
    WWW www = new WWW(this.Url, bytes);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
}

// simple handler for the WWW error/return data.
private IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
```

The problem is that I want to move this into a dll, that will be used by other dlls, not just monobehaviours, which as far as I can tell, means that StartCoroutine will no longer be available.

In .NET, Async and Await sounds similar, but I don't know how to use them.  Is there a way to duplicate the Coroutine functionality?  I do have access to UnityEngine.dll.

(If it is possible to use Coroutine without inheriting MonoBehaviour, that can work as well)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do using iterators. I've put some pseudo C# code here to give you an idea. You use `yield return` to return something from an iterator, which has the same behavior as `yield` in a theoretical coroutine. You can then store the iterators in a list, dictionary, or other structure to keep track of them, and run them all. Note that coroutines are *not* a natively supported feature of C#, and are usually implemented using enumerators. I think Unity does it in the same way.

```
enum Status
{
   Running, Success, Failure
}

// An example of a coroutine that does something until some
// condition is true.
IEnumerable<Status> Coroutine(arguments)
{
    while(true)
    {
        DoStuff();

        yield return Running;

        if(Condition())
        {
            yield return Success;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Keeps track of all running coroutines, and runs them till the end.
class CoroutineManager
{
     List<IEnumerator<Status> > Coroutines = new List<Enumerator<Status> >();

     // Starting a coroutine just means adding an enumerator to the list.
     // You might also want to be able to stop coroutines or delete them,
     // which might mean putting them into a dictionary
     public void StartCoroutine(Func<IEnumerable<Status> > func)
     {
         Coroutines.Add(func().GetEnumerator());
     }

     // Updating just means stepping through all the coroutines
     public void Update()
     {
         foreach(Enumerator<Status> routine in Coroutines)
         {
             routine.MoveNext();
         }
     }
}
```

You then just need to call

```
CoroutineManager.StartCoroutine(YourFunction)
```

to begin the coroutine. Somewhere in your code you also need to call

```
CoroutineManager.Update();
```

each tick.